# Shopware 6 Plugin: How to add auto-publish star rating threshold for Reviews without breaking backwards compatibility?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm currently extending the Review Plugin for Shopware 6. The plugin already has a `reviewSkipModeration` config option that automatically publishes any reviews submitted through the plugin.

I'd like to extend this to only auto-publish reviews above a certain star rating threshold, for example, 3 stars. But I need to do so without breaking existing functionality for users who already have the plugin installed.

I have added `autoPublishStars` config option to my config.xml:

```xml
    <card>
        <title>Basic Configuration</title>
        <title lang="de-DE">Allgemeine Konfiguration</title>
        <input-field type="bool">
            <name>reviewSkipModeration</name>
            <label>Accept reviews automatically</label>
            <label lang="de-DE">Bewertungen automatisch freigeschaltet</label>
            <defaultValue>true</defaultValue>
        </input-field>
        <input-field type="single-select">
            <name>autoPublishStars</name>
            <label>Auto Publish review with stars</label>
            <label lang="de-DE">Sterne vorausgewählt</label>
            <defaultValue>3</defaultValue>
            <options>
                <option>
                    <id>0</id>
                    <name>None</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">Keine</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <name>1 Star</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">1 Stern</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>2</id>
                    <name>2 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">2 Sterne</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>3</id>
                    <name>3 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">3 Sterne</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>4</id>
                    <name>4 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">4 Sterne</name>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <id>5</id>
                    <name>5 Stars</name>
                    <name lang="de-DE">5 Sterne</name>
                </option>
            </options>
        </input-field>
    </card>
```

[image: The added config option looks like this]

My `Config.php` looks like:

```php
use Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService;

class Config {
    protected string $pluginName = 'SwagReviews';
    protected string $path;
    protected bool $reviewSkipModeration;
    protected int $autoPublishStars;
  public function __construct(SystemConfigService $systemConfigService, ?string $salesChannelId = null) {
        $this->path = $this->pluginName . '.config.';
        $this->reviewSkipModeration = !is_null($systemConfigService->get($this->path . 'reviewSkipModeration', $salesChannelId)) ? 
            (bool) $systemConfigService->get($this->path . 'reviewSkipModeration', $salesChannelId) : false;

        $this->autoPublishStars = !is_null($systemConfigService->get($this->path . 'autoPublishStars', $salesChannelId)) ?
                (int) $systemConfigService->get($this->path . 'autoPublishStars', $salesChannelId) : 0;
    }

    public function getReviewSkipModeration(): bool {
        return $this->reviewSkipModeration;
    }
    public function getAutoPublishStars(): int {
        return (int) $this->autoPublishStars;
    }
}
```

My plugin's update function is

```
    public function update(UpdateContext $context): void {
        parent::update($context);
    }
```

My question is: What would be the cleanest way to add this configurable threshold in a backwards compatible way? I want to avoid changing the default behavior for existing users during an update. Kindly, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is that existing user's would see a change in behavior of the plugin and suddenly only reviews above 3 stars would be auto published, if you use those defaults?

I see two options:

1. Make the "0" option the default, so with the default values the plugin behaves the same after the update as before and everything will get auto published, if the skipReview option is on.
2. Or, if you want the 3 stars threshold to be the default for new users, you can use the plugin livecycle `update()` method to detect if the plugin was installed before. If so, write a configuration to "0 stars" s the behavior is restored to what the users were used to.

Concerning option 2 you can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77000377/288568).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I want to apply the second option. But I don't fully understand how I can achieve that. I have added the `update()` in the question. Kindly, tell me how I can do that. Secondly, do I need to write some `PHP` code in the controller for the config option I added(seen in the picture) to implement the functionality you described in option 2?

Comment: I have asked another question. Kindly, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/77084081/22289437

Comment: could you please vote (up) on my question?

Answer (score 1):

Get config service from the container and try something like:

```php
  public function update(UpdateContext $context): void {
        parent::update($context);
        
        // Get the currently installed version
        $version = $context->getCurrentPluginVersion(); 

        // Only update config if on version 1.6.3 or higher
        if (version_compare($version, '1.6.3', '>=')) {
            // Get config service from the container
            $configService = $this->container->get('Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService');       
        
            // Get the current value of the configuration
            $previousConfigVal  = $configService->getBool('SwagPlugin.config.reviewModeration');
            $newConfigVal = $previousConfigVal ? '0' : 'None';
               
            // Set the specified value as default
            $configService->set('SwagPlugin.config.autoPublishStars', $newConfigVal);     
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle this situation, you can begin by modifying your update method to check the value of the old boolean configuration and map it to the corresponding new multi-select configuration. Here's the updated code:

```php
public function update(UpdateContext $context): void
{
    parent::update($context);

    $prevVal = $this->config->getReviewSkipModeration();

    $currentVal = $prevVal ? 0 : 'None';

    $this->config->setAutoPublishStars($currentVal);
}
```