# Shopware 6 plugin: How to Remove/Migrate boolean config to multi-select config

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware6

I have a Shopware 6 plugin that currently uses a boolean config `reviewSkipModeration` value that automatically publishes any reviews submitted through the plugin:

```xml
<input-field type="bool">
  <name>reviewSkipModeration</name>
  <label>Accept reviews automatically</label>
  <defaultValue>true</defaultValue>
</input-field>
```

I want to migrate this to a multi-select config with the following options.:

- None
- 0 Stars
- 1 Star
- 2 Stars
- 3 Stars
- 4 Stars
- 5 Stars

In my update method, how can I migrate the data properly so:

- true maps to 0 Stars
- false maps to None
- and auto-publish reviews above a certain star rating threshold, for example, 3 stars. But I need to do so without breaking existing functionality for users who already have the plugin installed.

And delete the old boolean config value?

My update function of the plugin looks like:

```php
    public function update(UpdateContext $context): void {
        parent::update($context);
    }
```

But I'm not sure how to handle the mapping and deletion. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configurations are stored in the database and can be read/written with direct MySQL queries, or you can use the SystemConfigService.

```php
public function update(UpdateContext $context): void
{
    parent::update($context);

    // Get config service from the container
    $configService = $this->container->get('Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService');
    
    // Get the current value of the configuration
    $currentValue = $configService->getBool('YourPlugin.config.reviewSkipModeration');
    
    // Specify the new value
    $value = 'None'
    
    if($currentValue === true) {
        $value = '0 Stars'
    }
    
    // Set the specified value as default
    $configService->set('YourPlugin.config.reviewSkipModeration', $value);
}
```

Here is a basic example, but remember that you probably need to handle updating all sales channel configurations and the default (salesChannelId = null)

```php
$configService->getBool('YourPlugin.config.reviewSkipModeration', $salesChannelId);
$configService->set('YourPlugin.config.reviewSkipModeration', $value, $salesChannelId);
```

Comment: thanks, what about the case where I want to implement auto publish for the reviews above a threshold. For instance to publish reviews above 3 stars.

Comment: I can't think of anything else to do with this except to set "3 Stars" for true instead of "0 Stars". Unfortunately, the user can't specify anything when updating.

Comment: Ok it's not mandatory to use the Update function. Is there any way I can use a Multi-select config for this `reviewSkipModeration`? Instead of the Update function, the Controller or service can be used if the required functionality is met.

Comment: Yes, you can declare a config field as mult-select and you can set whatever value you want in the $configService->set() method.

Comment: I did not get this part "you probably need to handle updating all sales channel configurations and the default (salesChannelId = null)". Why sales channel config need to be updated? and how can I do that?

Comment: The plugin could have different configurations per sales channel, so you have to process them as well (`foreach` of the sales channels or so and apply the same logic)

Comment: @Alex Ezycod, I have asked another question. Kindly, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/77141183/22289437