# Shopware 6 plugin: Button added to review list in Shopware 6.1 no longer appears in 6.5

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have a plugin for **Shopware 6.1** that adds a button to the review list page in the administration. It uses a javascript file to override the `sw-review-list` component:

`index.js`

```js
import template from './sw-review-list.html.twig';

Shopware.Component.override('sw-review-list', {

  template: template

});
```

`sw-review-list.html.twig`

```html
{% block sw_review_list_smart_bar_header %}
    {% parent %}

    {% block custom_js_sw_review_list_smart_bar_actions %}
        <template slot="smart-bar-actions">
            {% block custom_js_list_smart_bar_actions_create %}
                <sw-button variant="secondary" v-bind:routerLink="{ name: 'plugin.custom.index' }">
                    {% block custom_js_list_smart_bar_header_title_text %}
                        {{ $t('custom_js.general.short') }}
                    {% endblock %}
                </sw-button>
            {% endblock %}
        </template>
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Both of the above files are in the directory `src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/plugin-custom/extension/sw-review-list`.

This used to work in **Shopware 6.1** and would add the button to the review list page in the admin. However, after upgrading to **Shopware 6.5**, the button no longer appears.

My `main.js`:

```js
import './module/plugin-custom';
```

I've tried recompiling the administration with:

```
./bin/build-administration.sh
```

But that did not fix the issue.

Does anyone know what would cause my custom button to no longer appear? Or have any suggestions on how I could fix this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you import it in the `src/Resources/app/administration/src/main.js`?
And is your Plugin listed when building the administration (`# Plugin "YourPlugin": Injected successfully`)?

Comment: @Ezycod Yes, I have imported my custom module `plugin-custom` in the `main.js`. I have also added that to the question. By " is your Plugin listed when building the administration" do you mean if my plugin is active at the moment I build the administration?

Comment: Yes, and it should be listed sometime in the build process with `# Plugin "YourPlugin": Injected successfully`, all the other Plugins including the Storefront, etc. are listed there.
Otherwise, is it shown in the browser when you put a console.log in the main.js? 
To make sure that it is really built and loaded.

Comment: @Ezycod thanks a lot. Could you please vote-up my question?

Comment: @Ezycod Thanks a lot. It worked. You can copy your comments and paste it as an answer. I want to have it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check everything to make sure that your administration extension is built and loaded?

1. Make sure that everything is imported in your `<YourPlugin>/src/Resources/app/administration/src/main.js`.
2. Make sure that your plugin is installed and activated.
3. Take a close look at the build process, at some time all Bundles/Plugins should be listed there, including your plugin with a message like `# Plugin "YourPlugin": Injected successfully`.
4. Check your console output for errors and maybe add a console.log if it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have asked a new question. Kindly, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/77180656/22289437